# R filter not retaining values less than -10

Tags: r

I am using R to retain values which are below a condition, it is working but not including row where log10 column has values more than -10. Below is a part of the table. I want to select all the values in log10 column which are between -8 to -14.

My table:

```
chr          rs       ps    af      beta       p_wald             log10
1    5 S5_10683198 10683198 0.025 0.5628516 9.422555e-15 -14.0258313188689
2    8   S8_361882   361882 0.025 0.5295581 6.825981e-13 -12.1658349249069
3    8  S8_7385592  7385592 0.021 0.5421677 5.944847e-12 -11.2258593181539
4    2   S2_276875   276875 0.025 0.4899961 1.342672e-11 -10.8720300677393
5    3  S3_7418268  7418268 0.021 0.4906429 1.711510e-11 -10.7666205590256
6    2 S2_14021380 14021380 0.025 0.5080194 2.511021e-11 -10.6001496552098
7    3 S3_13987777 13987777 0.021 0.4595375 2.664140e-11 -10.5744429568178
30   8  S8_7395237  7395237 0.021 0.4186731 3.995514e-09 -8.39842734325747
31   6  S6_7387034  7387034 0.028 0.4266190 4.957138e-09 -8.30476899075709
32   5 S5_11495292 11495292 0.028 0.4575658 5.080677e-09 -8.29407841413843
33   1 S1_15059335 15059335 0.025 0.4183669 5.106630e-09 -8.29186560773669
19430   7 S7_14557672 14557672 0.037 -0.1892856 0.005395347 -2.26798061857347
19431   7  S7_2217818  2217818 0.055 -0.1286663 0.005396288 -2.26790488007629
19432   8  S8_3013554  3013554 0.030  0.1430241 0.005396304 -2.26790359239457
19433   4  S4_1154225  1154225 0.045 -0.1572871 0.005396518  -2.2678863700186
19434   1 S1_21402062 21402062 0.074  0.1159478 0.005396604 -2.26787944906923
19435   2  S2_6176209  6176209 0.030  0.1522105 0.005396680 -2.26787333297322
```

I am using this R code

```
maf2 <- maf1[ which(maf1$log10 >= -8.00), ]
```

my results

```
chr          rs       ps    af      beta       p_wald             log10
30   8  S8_7395237  7395237 0.021 0.4186731 3.995514e-09 -8.39842734325747
31   6  S6_7387034  7387034 0.028 0.4266190 4.957138e-09 -8.30476899075709
32   5 S5_11495292 11495292 0.028 0.4575658 5.080677e-09 -8.29407841413843
33   1 S1_15059335 15059335 0.025 0.4183669 5.106630e-09 -8.29186560773669
```

The results skipping first 7 rows with > -10.

What to change in the code.

Thanks,

Vinod

Comment: The first 7 log10 values are NOT > -8, that's why.

Comment: change ```-8``` to ```-10```

Comment: If  I include -10, the table is empty.

Comment: I'm guessing a typo. What does `maf1[ which(maf1$log10 >= -10), ]` return? Also The compalint in your problem title is exactly what **should** be happening.

Comment: it is an empty table.

Comment: OK... Need [MCVE]. Post `dput(maf1[ 1:20, ])`

Comment: At least check the column class - sounds like that column might not be numeric even though it should be.

Comment: Good point Gregor. Character variable would not throw an error but would allow that sort of comparison.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the issue, the column class is character. Thanks Gregor for noticing. I was completely avoiding it.